# Learn SharePoint

Tags: sharepoint-foundation, sharepoint-online

Im newbie and I wanna learn SharePoint 2010 from scratch about doing customized coding. Not learning about the template part.

What book/material can you suggest?

Comment: Are you comfortable doing C#? HTML? CSS? Javascript?

Comment: I'm comfortable with C# and HTML. I'm stille newbie in CSS and javascript.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I wrote a blog post on tackling this kind of question, what you need to know if you're learning:

- [SharePoint Development – What to Learn?](http://e-junkie-chronicles.blogspot.co.uk/2012/02/sharepoint-development-what-to-learn.html)

In short, read up on the workings and capabilities of:

- SharePoint Foundation
- SharePoint Server
- Office365 SharePoint Online
- SharePoint Designer
- Visual Studio (in particular the project item templates, as mentioned in another answer)
- ASP.NET - SharePoint is in effect a very large ASP.NET application. Your knowledge of ASP.NET will benefit you when coding, although there are large differences in how stuff is done in SharePoint
- C#, not only the syntax and basics of programming in C#, but also the various object models available (Managed Server Side, Managed Client Side)
- Other ways of getting data out of SharePoint: ECMAScript (JavaScript) client side, as well as all the various web services, REST interfaces, etc.

Comment: 1. Are you talking about the classical asp.net and not asp.net mvc?

Comment: 2. Is there another option to retrieve data from the database except binding list? Possiblility to use Entity framework, Nhibernate or something similiar  for Sharepoint?

Comment: 3. I don't understand based of this sentence "..but also the various object models available (Managed Server Side, Managed Client Side)"?

Comment: 1) ASP.NET (not MVC) 2) It is not supported to connect directly to SharePoint content databases, you must use the object model provided 3) This post on MSDN describes the different object models available: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj164060.aspx

Comment: Thank you for answering my previous questions.
2. "you must use the object model provided", can you provide some concrete example?

Comment: Ok, so instead of just going to the database table to select data you want using SQL or entity frameworks, you would use an SPQuery object against a given SPList object, like in this example: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms457534.aspx

Comment: And the reason for the object model being in the way: you can never guarantee where the content database is, or what web application you're running under, or what identity/permissions you have - SP handles all of that for you when you use the classes in the object model.

Comment: Jamey you have nailed it quite well

Answer (score 2):

For me there is only 1 place to start:

[Channel 9 SharePoint Search](http://channel9.msdn.com/search?term=sharepoint)

They have videos from basics to advanced.

There are also plenty of articles on the WIKI here and plenty of questions with high votes in here to review and research.

Also just install it and take a look around.

Answer (score 1):

**Channel9** is worth it, but there are many other resources and books you can refer to! Before deep diving into development, I suggest you should know about the components SharePoint is based and on and what can you do with development in SharePoint, like look into different Project Templates you have in Visual Studio under SharePoint category and understand what each one of them do! Because there are many things that can be done OOB, where newbie think to develop [happened to me :)]

These resources will be helpful:

**Books:**

[Microsoft SharePoint Foundation 2010 Step by Step](https://web.archive.org/web/20150104073420/http://blogs.msdn.com/b/microsoft_press/archive/2011/02/15/new-book-microsoft-sharepoint-foundation-2010-step-by-step.aspx) [This book really helped me in understanding when to go for development]

[WROX: Beginning SharePoint 2010 Development](https://www.wiley.com/en-nl/Beginning+SharePoint+2010+Development-p-9780470584637)

**Free Training Material:**

[Sharepoint 2010 Developer Training Kit](https://web.archive.org/web/20190702091409/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=6184)
[SharePoint 2010 Resources for Developers](https://www.microsoft.com/nl-nl/microsoft-365/sharepoint/collaboration?ms.officeurl=sharepoint&rtc=1)
[Training > SharePoint 2010 get started](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/)
[Advanced developer training for SharePoint 2010](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/)
[SharePoint 2010: Professional Developer Evaluation Guide and Walkthroughs](https://web.archive.org/web/20160308074032/http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=7204)

Answer (score 1):

- [Essential SharePoint 2010: Overview, Governance, and Planning (Addison-Wesley Microsoft Technology)](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0321700759)
- [Microsoft® SharePoint® Designer 2010 Step by Step](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0735627339)
- [Sams Teach Yourself SharePoint 2010 Development in 24 Hours](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0672335794)

they are good Books.

i had a Book "Essential SharePoint 2007 2ND EDITION" which really helped me a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at PluralSight as they have bunch of videos on SharePoint 2010 that you can learn from it.

WebSite: https://www.pluralsight.com/search?q=SharePoint%202010&categories=all