# Novice Developer

Tags: development, training

I have not been able to find any related subject here related to training patterns, Some of us who have gone through the C# basics and moderate courses as well as some other courses may be at loss like I am as to how a person would go through a project from start to finish.
 I was wondering if there is a book out there or a site what would hit the ground running with a project from concept to deployment, just pure coding and testing within SharePoint framework, this would be a HUGE help. Thanks.

Comment: Welcome Samin to the SharePoint Stackexchange, you have asked quite a generic question. Have you gone through any books, tutorials yourself ?

Comment: This is kind of a duplicate of quite a few threads. See http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/52937/learn-sharepoint and http://sharepoint.stackexchange.com/questions/3297/an-introduction-to-sharepoint-2010

Comment: I say kind of above because those threads are 2010 specific but many of the resources mentioned are still applicable.

Comment: @Samin - which version of SharePoint 2010 or 2013 are you targeting? The app development model has changed.

Answer (score 8):

Free Resources for SharePoint 2013

**MS Virtual Academy** (not just developer related)

- **[Enterprise Developer Jump Start](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/liveevents/enterprise-developer-camp-jump-start#?fbid=8q68Sx1kYgV)** (tangentially related and scheduled for Feb 4, 2014)
- **[Tuning SQL Server 2012 for SharePoint 2013 Jump Start](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/tuning-sql-server-2012-for-sharepoint-2013-jump-start#?fbid=8q68Sx1kYgV)**
- **[Developing Microsoft SharePoint Server 2013 Core Solutions Jump Start](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/developing-microsoft-sharepoint-server-2013-core-solutions-jump-start#?fbid=8q68Sx1kYgVhttp://Developing%20Microsoft%20SharePoint%20Server%202013%20Core%20Solutions%20Jump%20Start)**
- **[Developing SharePoint Server 2013 Advanced Solutions Jump Start](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/developing-sharepoint-server-advanced-solutions-jump-start)**
- **[Office Guides: Apps for Office and SharePoint](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/office-guides-apps-for-office-and-sharepoint#?fbid=8q68Sx1kYgV)**

HTML 5 and ASP.NET MVC are the first two exams on the [*MCSD: SharePoint Applications*](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/mcsd-sharepoint-apps-certification.aspx) track.

- **[HTML5 & CSS3 Fundamentals: Development for Absolute Beginners](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/html5-css3-fundamentals-development-for-absolute-beginners#?fbid=8q68Sx1kYgV)**
- **[Developing in HTML5 with JavaScript and CSS3 Jump Start](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/learn-html5-with-javascript-css3-jumpstart-training#?fbid=8q68Sx1kYgV)**
- **[Developing ASP.NET MVC 4.5 Web Applications Jump Start](http://www.microsoftvirtualacademy.com/training-courses/developing-asp-net-mvc-4-web-applications-jump-start#?fbid=8q68Sx1kYgV)**

**Channel 9** - I am only going to list a few. Check out the [SharePoint tag on their site](https://channel9.msdn.com/Tags/sharepoint).

- **[Developing Apps for Office and Sharepoint](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Reimagine-SharePoint-Development/Developing-Apps-for-Office-and-Sharepoint)**
- **[Building a SharePoint Pop-up Lab in Windows Azure](https://channel9.msdn.com/Series/Windows-Azure-Virtual-Machines-and-Networking-Tutorials/Building-a-SharePoint-2010-Pop-up-Lab-in-Windows-Azure)**
- **[Introduction to SharePoint 2013 App Model](https://channel9.msdn.com/Blogs/cdndevs/AppsForSharePoint2013)**

[Free eBooks from Microsoft](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/mssmallbiz/archive/2013/06/18/huge-collection-of-free-microsoft-ebooks-for-you-including-office-office-365-sharepoint-sql-server-system-center-visual-studio-web-development-windows-windows-azure-and-windows-server.aspx) on a range of topics including SharePoint administration and development.

**Paid Training**

[PluralSight](http://pluralsight.com/training/Courses#sharepoint) is the best online training site for SharePoint administration and development. They have 95 courses and are adding new ones pretty regularly. I have no affiliation, but I have been a subscriber for a few years now.

[Microsoft offers courses on SharePoint development](http://www.microsoft.com/learning/en-us/mcsd-sharepoint-apps-certification.aspx) as well. You can go to an MS partner to take it. Just check out the "Optional Training" links.

Answer (score 4):

I say this with some reservation, but I did find this book: SharePoint 2010 Development  with Visual Studio 2010 by Eric Carter, Boris Scholl and Peter Jausovec helpful.  My reservations are due to typos and some omissions from the text and code.  I learned from this book by searching sites like this one when the code would not compile.  I had to figure out how to fix what was not working from the book examples.  In the end, I learned from it despite its shortcomings.

Comment: I haven't read that book, but it might be more realistic than you think.  Real world SharePoint development is exactly like that.  MSDN and the blogosphere are full of stuff that doesn't work, omits important details, or only addresses the most trivial of use cases. Then you are left having to fill in the missing or inaccurate bits yourself.

Comment: Agreed.  I reviewed the book on Amazon. It was definitely helpful.